# Calling getSibling() in R to extract single nodes from XML file causes crash

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I am attempting to extract one node at a time from a very large (~620 MB) XML file using an R script. Each main node that I want to access corresponds to a different drug, and all of the nodes are parallel to each other. My aim is to process the entire file, one node at a time, since trying to read the entire file into memory does not work with the XML parser in R.

I have significantly truncated my large XML file into a much smaller example file that contains only 4 nodes; the beginning of this XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drugbank xmlns="http://www.drugbank.ca" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd" version="5.0" exported-on="2017-07-06">
<drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13" updated="2016-08-17">
  <drugbank-id primary="true">DB00001</drugbank-id>
  <drugbank-id>BTD00024</drugbank-id>
  <drugbank-id>BIOD00024</drugbank-id>
  <name>Lepirudin</name>
  <description>Lepirudin is identical to natural hirudin except for substitution of leucine for isoleucine at the N-terminal end of the molecule and the absence of a sulfate group on the tyrosine at position 63. It is produced via yeast cells. Bayer ceased the production of lepirudin (Refludan) effective May 31, 2012.</description>
  <cas-number>138068-37-8</cas-number>
  <unii>Y43GF64R34</unii>
  <state>liquid</state>
  <groups>
    <group>approved</group>
  </groups>
```

Having reviewed the available options, and wanting to use the R script that I have already written that extracts desired fields from the XML file (it works for small XML files, but fails for the large file), it seems that using the getSibling() function in the XML library in R is my best choice. The following example code (from http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/XML/html/addSibling.html ) works to extract the single node in this example file:

```
f = system.file("exampleData", "job.xml", package = "XML")
tt = as(xmlParse(f), "XMLHashTree")
x = xmlRoot(tt, skip = FALSE)
DesiredOutput <- getSibling(x)
# I’m still not sure how to “walk” to the next sibling after the above process completes, since this example file only contains one node, and there is no simple way to increment a counter using the above code
```

That example job.xml file begins as follows:

```
<!-- Initial Comment -->
<gjob:Helping xmlns:gjob="http://www.gnome.org/some-location">
  <gjob:Jobs>

    <gjob:Job>
      <gjob:Project ID="3"/>
      <gjob:Application>GBackup</gjob:Application>
      <gjob:Category>Development</gjob:Category>

      <gjob:Update>
        <gjob:Status>Open</gjob:Status>
        <gjob:Modified>Mon, 07 Jun 1999 20:27:45 -0400 MET DST</gjob:Modified>
        <gjob:Salary>USD 0.00</gjob:Salary>
      </gjob:Update>

      <gjob:Developers>
        <gjob:Developer>
        </gjob:Developer>
      </gjob:Developers>
```

However, if I substitute my own XML file (small version of the full file; I have checked that it is legitimate XML format, as my R script correctly runs to process it), the following code crashes R:

```
f = "MyTruncatedExampleFile.xml" -> this line causes R to crash
tt = as(xmlParse(f), "XMLHashTree")
x = xmlRoot(tt, skip = FALSE)
DesiredOutput <- getSibling(x)
```

Can anyone suggest why my own small XML file would cause a crash, but the example job.xml file runs correctly? Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: could it be a bug of r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it seems to be due to the undeclared namespace prefix in the truncated XML causing the crash: `xmlns="http://www.drugbank.ca"`. If you remove this, the method does not crash R. Do note: undeclared namespaces is valid in XML documents. So, this issue should be raised with XML package authors. Also, since `<drug>` does not have a sibling in truncated XML, `xmlChildren()` is used below in place of `getSibling()`.

```
# CRASHES
f = "DrugBank.xml"
tt = as(xmlParse(f), "XMLHashTree")
x = xmlRoot(tt, skip = FALSE)
DesiredOutput <- xmlChildren(x)[[1]]
DesiredOutput

# NO CRASHES
f = "DrugBank_oth.xml"                      # REMOVED UNDEFINED NAMESPACE PREFIX
tt = as(xmlParse(f), "XMLHashTree")
x = xmlRoot(tt, skip = FALSE)
DesiredOutput <- xmlChildren(x)[[1]]
DesiredOutput
```

As a workaround without modifying original XML, consider `getNodeSet` where you define a prefix for the special namespace and XPath to the children level of the root wih `/*/*`. The index `[[1]]` is used to take the first instead of all nodes. Here, *web* is used as prefix but it can be anything.

```
# NO CRASHES
f = "DrugBank.xml"
doc = xmlParse(f)
nmsp = c(web="http://www.drugbank.ca")      # DEFINE NAMESPACE PREFIX

DesiredOutput <- getNodeSet(doc, "/*/*", nmsp)[[1]]
DesiredOutput

# <drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13" updated="2016-08-17">
#   <drugbank-id primary="true">DB00001</drugbank-id>
#   <drugbank-id>BTD00024</drugbank-id>
#   <drugbank-id>BIOD00024</drugbank-id>
#   <name>Lepirudin</name>
#   <description>Lepirudin is identical to natural hirudin except for 
#                substitution of leucine for isoleucine at the N-terminal 
#                end of the molecule and the absence of a sulfate group on 
#                the tyrosine at position 63. It is produced via yeast 
#                cells. Bayer ceased the production of lepirudin (Refludan) 
#                effective May 31, 2012.</description>
#   <cas-number>138068-37-8</cas-number>
#   <unii>Y43GF64R34</unii>
#   <state>liquid</state>
#   <groups>
#     <group>approved</group>
#   </groups>
# </drug>
```